# Using Interface in a Class for Function

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

This program totally working the way I want it to be. There is just one line I can't understand from the bottom of `Frompanel`. I just learned this from tutorial video.

This is my interface

```
public interface StringListener {
    public void EmitText(String Text);
}
```

This is Formpanel Class

```
public class FormPanel extends JPanel {

    StringListener txtListener;

    private String Name;
    private String Age;
    private String Address;


    private JTextField NameF;
    private JTextField AgeF;
    private JTextField AddressF;

    private JButton Ok;

    public FormPanel() {

        NameF = new JTextField(8);
        AgeF = new JTextField(8);
        AddressF = new JTextField(8);

        Ok = new JButton("Ok");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        Ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Name = NameF.getText().toString();
                Age = AgeF.getText().toString();
                Address = AddressF.getText().toString();

                txtListener.EmitText("\n Hello! " + Name + "\n");
                txtListener.EmitText("you are " + Age + " years old \n");
                txtListener.EmitText("you lived in " + Address);

            }
        });
    }

    public void showInfo(StringListener Listener) {
        this.txtListener = Listener; /// I cant Understand this Line

    }
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to ask a question. Not to throw a wall of badly foratted code at us and letting us guess what your question might be.

Comment: Could you please mark somehow the line that you do not understand and explain what you do not understand.

Comment: @AlexR You can see it at the bottom of the formpanel class(just after the interface) sorry for this unorganized code.

Comment: @CapsLock The line is a simple assignment. However, if you edit the question to explain what you do and don't understand about that line, it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The line simply sets `txtListerner` to the given `StringListener`. You migth be confused because you've written `Listener` with a capital L.